# Hello,i want to get a string with all symbols in lower case.The code doesn't want to work, and i dont't understand where i could make error

Tags: javascript

```
let s = 'Hello i Am Jendarme'
function foo(string) 
{
        for (i = 0; i < string.length - 1; i++) {
          (string[i].toUpperCase() == string[i]) ? string[i].toLowerCase() 
          : string[i]
        }
    console.log(string)
}
foo(s)
```

is returning initial value the string(s)

Comment: The code does want to work.  It really wants to.  But your code does nothing to change the string, or generate a new string.  Your code just looks at the string.

Comment: If you need return all string in lower case, just use s.toLowerCase();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `console.log(string)` **without** modifying it in any way.

`.toLowerCase()` **returns** the lowercased value. It doesn't modify it in-place.

You need to assign the result of your ternary operation somewhere.

```
string[i] = (string[i].toUpperCase() == string[i]) ?
      string[i].toLowerCase() :
      string[i];
```

Conditionally lowercasing a character if it isn't lowercased already is horrifically inefficient though.

```
function foo(string) {
    console.log(string.toLowerCase());
}
```

… will give you the same result.